# Sending CSRF token in react with php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, session-cookies

I am creating a web app in react and using php as backend. I had created many apis in php for different functionalities like login, signup, chats, etc. But i want to secure my POST request with CSRF token. I have not idea to send CSRF in react to php API file.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. Set a CSRF cookie from the PHP backend ***(Look into the setcookie() function)***

**2**. Allow credentials in your AJAX request
***(This way your CSRF cookie will be sent along with the request in the headers)***

> [EXAMPLE] in axios, its:
>
> `axios.post('/login', { username: '', password: '' }, { withCredentials: true })`

**3**. Read the CSRF cookie from the request headers in the backend, then verify it ***(Check the $_SERVER superglobal for this, apache servers do have a custom function for this too IIRC)***